# Is it possible to load different "_layouts" with ajax for certain pages?

Tags: templating, ajax, layout

I've followed this [tutorial](https://designbycosmic.com/journal/craft-cms-ajax-page-transitions-with-history-pushstate) by Zack Spear. It leaves your website with a header and footer that stay constant while the body of the page is loaded in through AJAX when you change pages.

Is it possible to have different _layout templates used for different pages with this approach or can it only be one? Could I hide the header on certain URLs? Could I show a secondary menu on specific urls?

Answer (score 1):

Although you couldn't necessarily change the _layout template with the method given in that tutorial. What you could do is include the header 
the templates rather than in the _layout.html for each template and change it out with another header in the other specific URLs. Or hide it, or whatever you like.